# Finding meson dependency with CMake

Tags: c, cmake, meson-build

I'm trying to compile [gst-python](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-python)
with meson.

I'm on windows, and don't have pkg-config.

So I try to make meson find a dependency (Gstreamer) with meson.
Meson finds cmake, but I can't set CMAKE_MODULE_PATH so cmake will find my Findgstreamer-1.0.cmake file.

I saw on meson docs that you can set cmake_module_path option, but it didn't work:

```
gst_dep = dependency('gstreamer-1.0', version : gst_req, method : 'cmake',
 cmake_module_path : 'C:/Users/dvir4/Desktop/playgound/cmake',
  fallback : ['gstreamer', 'gst_dep'])
```

still produces the error:

```
Run-time dependency gstreamer-1.0 found: NO (tried cmake)
Looking for a fallback subproject for the dependency gstreamer-1.0
```

Somehow i need to set up the cmake variable CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.
I Couldn't find a way to set it via meson, or as environment variable.

How can i let cmake find the dependecy ?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm on windows, and don't have pkg-config.

Its easy to build and will make many projects work. https://github.com/pkgconf/pkgconf

(Not that I'm saying it can't be done without as I'm unfamiliar with GStreamers builds)

Comment: If you're on Windows and you're using MSYS2 as a shell you can easily install pkg-config with `pacman -S --noconfirm pkg-config`.